# Selenium Python Drop Down Not Controllable

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to select and control a drop down menu on the www.ziprecruiter.com website using Selenium called radius. Since I'm a beginner I cant seem to figure out why I cant control this one drop down radius menu. I have tried using find by ID, name, Xpath, and select but nothing seems to be working. I want to select the option "25 miles" in the radius drop down menu, any ideas?

```
<label class="filter_headline" for="search_filters_radius">Distance</label>
<menu id="select-menu-search_filters_radius" class="select-menu-menu" tabindex="-1">
<button class="select-menu-header">Anywhere</button>
<div class="select-menu-submenu-wrapper">
<div class="select-menu-submenu-inner" style="left: 63.0667px; top: 145px;">
<menu class="select-menu-submenu">
<button class="select-menu-item select-menu-selected">Anywhere</button>
<button class="select-menu-item">Within 100 miles</button>
<button class="select-menu-item">Within 50 miles</button>
<button class="select-menu-item">Within 25 miles</button>**
<button class="select-menu-item">Within 10 miles</button>
<button class="select-menu-item">Within 5 miles</button>
</menu>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes dropdowns are created using `SELECT` tags but this is becoming less frequent as sites want the dropdown feel with different styling than the typical `SELECT` will give them. What you have on this page is an instance of a dropdown that isn't a `SELECT` tag. If it were a Select tag you would be able to take advantage of the built in methods, `select_by_*()`.

Since this is not a SELECT tag, what you need to do is to click the top level element to expose the options then click on the desired option, in your case "Within 25 miles."

```
searchText = "Within 25 miles"
// clicks the "Anywhere" dropdown
driver.find_element_by_id("select-menu-search_filters_radius")).click();
// selects the desired option by text
driver.find_element_by_id("//menu[@id='select-menu-search_filters_radius']//button[text()='" + searchText + "']")).click();
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! I appreciate it.